# Shared Element Transition from Recycelrview to Activity

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, adapter, transition

Please tell me why this is happening? What am I doing wrong?
[screen video](https://yadi.sk/i/z-9xvtQ14hqsUQ)

Listener

```
public interface NoteListener {
void onNoteClicked(Note note, int position, RelativeLayout noteLayout);
```

}

Adapter

```
NoteViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        ...
        relativeLayoutNote = itemView.findViewById(R.id.rl_note);

        itemView.setOnClickListener(v -> noteListener.onNoteClicked(sortedList.get(getAdapterPosition()),
                getAdapterPosition(),  relativeLayoutNote));
    }
```

MainActivity

```
@Override
public void onNoteClicked(Note note, int position, RelativeLayout noteLayout) {
    if (!isClick) {
        DetailNoteActivity.start(this, note, findViewById(R.id.rl_note));
        isClick = true;
    }
}
```

Detail Activity

```
public static void start(Activity caller, Note note, RelativeLayout noteLayout) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(caller, DetailNoteActivity.class);
    ActivityOptions options = ActivityOptions.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(
            caller, noteLayout, "note");
    if (note != null) {
        intent.putExtra(NOTE, note);
    }
    caller.startActivity(intent, options.toBundle());
}
```

item_note

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
...
android:background="@drawable/background_note"
android:transitionName="note">...
```

activity_detail

```
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:transitionName="note"
        android:animateLayoutChanges="true">...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided in the following way, possibly clumsy, if there is another way please write. Added the following to MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NoteListener {
...
private RelativeLayout noteLayout;
...
@SuppressLint("SupportAnnotationUsage")
@AnimRes
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ....
    noteLayout = findViewById(R.id.rl_note);
    ...

@Override
public void onNoteClicked(Note note, RelativeLayout noteLayout) {
    this.noteLayout = noteLayout;
    if (!isClick) {
        DetailNoteActivity.start(this, note, noteLayout);
        isClick = true;
    }
}
```